# Connector.open(String s) causes a RuntimeException

Tags: java, sockets, runtimeexception, connector

I have a little program here where I try to create a server socket on the port 1234.

```
public class SocketTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {           
        ServerSocketConnection scn;
        scn = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://:1234");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I get a RuntimeException caused by the Connector.open() method.

UPDATE: Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
at ej.ecom.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:61)
at SocketTest.main(SocketTest.java:12)
```

I tried to disable my antivirus and firewall and to put the creation of socket to a separate thread, but nothing changes. I feel I am making a basic mistake here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ServerSocketConnection` is in `Java ME` isn't it ?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace? Does `Connector` belong to a specific API?

Comment: Why not `ServerSocket()`?

Comment: Yes, this is a specific API for a micro-controller: `ej.ecom.io.Connector`.
Stack trace:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
 at ej.ecom.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:61)
 at SocketTest.main(SocketTest.java:12)`

Comment: Thanks for showing your main method awhole. It is very important that you exposed it instead of what is really needed -- the exeption message.

Comment: I cannot use ServerSocket(). It is not included in the platform I am working on.

Comment: Added the stack trace to the post.

Comment: are you sure `"socket://:1234"` is right?

Comment: Yes, it is from the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/ServerSocketConnection.html